# Module (Laminas\Crypt) could not be initialized

Tags: php, composer-php, bcrypt, laminas

I want to use Bcrypt of Laminas-Crypt package in one of my files. After running

`composer require laminas/laminas-crypt`,
`composer dump-autoload`,
`composer update`

I declared a use statement in my controller:
`use Laminas\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt;`
The application loaded without any errors, but as far as I am concerned, all namespaces should be registered in config/modules.config.php for the autoloader to load the namespaces accordingly. After adding Laminas\Crypt namespace to the folder the application threw an exception:

`Uncaught Laminas\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Laminas\Crypt) could not be initialized. in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpLessons\Shortly\vendor\laminas\laminas-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php:180`

My question is:

1. Can the application function properly without the namespace of the used package being defined in the config/modules.config.php of root directory?
2. How can the exception be handled?

Edit:
Here is the relevant part of composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1.0",
        "laminas/laminas-component-installer": "^3.0",
        "laminas/laminas-development-mode": "^3.2",
        "laminas/laminas-skeleton-installer": "^1.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc": "^3.3.4",
        "laminas/laminas-db": "^2.12.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc-form": "^2.0.0",
        "laminas/laminas-json": "^3.2",
        "laminas/laminas-log": "^2.13.1",
        "laminas/laminas-cli": "^1.1.1",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc-i18n": "^1.2.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc-plugins": "^1.1.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc-middleware": "^2.0.0",
        "laminas/laminas-session": "^2.10.0",
        "laminas/laminas-di": "^3.2.2",
        "laminas/laminas-view": "^2.25",
        "laminas/laminas-form": "3.7",
        "laminas/laminas-crypt": "^3.9",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "laminas/laminas-mail": "^2.20",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.4",
        "symfony/cache": "^5.4",
        "doctrine/common": "^3.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "^5.3"
    },
```

and modules.config.php from config/autoload:

```
return [
    'Laminas\Cache',
    'Laminas\Paginator',
    'Laminas\Mail',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Laminas\Session',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Middleware',
    'Laminas\Mvc\I18n',
    'Laminas\Form',
    'Laminas\I18n',
    'Laminas\Log',
    'Laminas\InputFilter',
    'Laminas\Filter',
    'Laminas\Hydrator',
    'Laminas\Di',
    'Laminas\Db',
    'Laminas\Router',
    'Laminas\Validator',
    'Laminas\DeveloperTools',
    'Laminas\Diactoros',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Application',
    'User',
    'Pages',
];
```

Comment: You need to configure the Laminas module first. Please add your `composer.json` file to the question by [edit]ing it. You can limit it to the relevant parts. There is normally a configuration step between the `composer require` and the `composer dump-autoload` invocation.

Comment: Since there is no configuration (factories, dependencies, aliases, ...) in `Laminas\Crypt`, then it is not required to add it in `modules.config.php`. Concerning the exception, well.. This is an error that can occurs only in development environment (unless someone is doing such things in production, but this is a different story), hence there is no need to "handle" it.